# dot net nuke 5 administrator account needs more emails

Tags: dotnetnuke

I need more than one email account to receive an email of a new user registration in dot net nuke 5 portal.

can you please guide me as the dot net nuke administrator account allows only one email address.

Regards,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe DNN explicitly allows you to do this. I would suggest the best way to do it would be to create an email address (e.g. administrators@yoursite.com) that acts as a distribution list and forwards the emails on to those who need to receive it. You could then set that email address as the email for the Portal Administrator.